# how to test xqueries manually where elements >200?

Tags: xquery, osb

currently i am working on one of the service where consumer can send 250 elements in request and i need to do the mapping for all inbound elements using xquery transformation.

**Can someone let me know if there is any optimal way or any tool  to test the mapping of 250 elements in one go ?**

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use.

https://github.com/TrentBartlem/osbutils/tree/master/XQTestFramework

I put the jar into my maven repo (along with various OSB/weblogic jars), then write JUnit test cases. Doesn't even need an OSB server running.